# Angular 4 typescript: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm initializing an array and trying to push elements into the array. But I get this error saying Cannot read property 'list' of undefined.

```
list: Array<any> = [];
this.data.forEach(function(element) {
      this.list = [];

    });
    this.data.forEach(function(element) {

        this.list.push({
          'name' : this.url
        })
  });
```

Even though I'm initializing the array, it is saying as undefined

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: use an arrow function to preserve the "this" context like (element) => { } instead of function(element) { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an arrow function to preserve the "this" context like

```
(element) => { }
```

instead of

```
function(element) { }
```

arrow functions don't create new scope, regular functions do, so "this" refers to the function scope (where list is undeclared) in a normal function declaration rather than the component scope (where list is declared) like you want.

generally, you will be using arrow functions much more often than not. regular function declaration is the more specialized case.